# RabbitMQ - way of working of ackonwledgments and requeue/remove

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

I tried to find answer to my question in the Internet, but no effect. From what I know when I got some message it is hold in queue until the moment I ack it. So it may be very long, in particular infinitely longly. At it is ok for me.

However, the question is about what in case of sending `nack` ??
it is requeued ? What does it mean ? Don't remove it form queue or remove it  and push at the end of queue ?

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

According to [the RabbitMQ documentation on NACKs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html), when a consumer sends a NACK, it also specifies if the message should be requeued or not. Example with Pika's [basic_nack](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/modules/adapters/blocking.html#pika.adapters.blocking_connection.BlockingChannel.basic_nack):

```
channel.basic_nack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag, requeue = True)
```

If the `requeue` parameter is set to `False`, the message will be discarded by RabbitMQ (and therefore lost).

If the `requeue` parameter is set to `True`, the message will stay in the queue until a consumer receives and ACKs it.